# How to share a tethered iPhone internet connection with VirtualBox guest?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I mostly connect to my Linux distros to the  internet via a USB iPhone tethered connection (MyWi app).

I have just installed an Windows XP guest OS via Virtualbox on Ubuntu 12.04.

How do I connect the guest OS to the internet via my tethered iPhone connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the network setup with your VM. If you just have a NAT connection everything should work out of the box.

If you have a bridged connection you must change the bridge device from your existing network card to the new Ethernet device created for the USB tethering; most likely the device will be `usb0`.

Comment: Just as you rightly pointed out, I have a bridge network so I chose a Bridge adapter and finally chose my tethered connection named eth1

Comment: for ubuntu 16 the name is enp0s20u3